# How to install LARAVEL 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, web-hosting

how to install laravel on hostinger server/ any other free hosting server. I had learned and done working codes in localhost. But i would like to run it on a real server.

> Laravel Version : 5
>
> PHP Version Server :5.5.35

1) I had copied the full laravel code to "/home/< username >/"

2) copied the files in /home//laravel/public to /home/< username >/public_html

But it shows an error.

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home//public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home//public_html/index.php on line 22

**Answer :**
Use Heroku Server as @lciamp Suggested in the comment

**Clarification :**

Please suggest me a list of Payed Servers which support Laravel Framework

Comment: Here: https://laravel.com/docs/master#installing-laravel

Comment: don't think he has cli access so the doc's wont help him

Comment: Laravel can't (officially) be setup in a subdirectory of the host root. You will need to set up a virtual host (something that I doubt is possible with free hosting). You could follow https://medium.com/@kunalnagar/deploying-laravel-5-on-godaddy-shared-hosting-888ec96f64cd#.v9nj8jlym to see if it helps.

Comment: here is how to do it on heroku. It's actually really easy after you delete the env.example file. http://www.shohan.net/2015/12/07/how-to-deploy-your-first-laravel-5-application-on-heroku/

Comment: @ThomasEaso `'/home//public_html/` is not a valid directory. Where is your username?

Comment: Save yourself a lot of time and headache and just use a VPS.

Comment: It's probably permission  issue. Add read permissions to bootstrap/autoload.php if you have access

Comment: @Qevo Username is there its considered as a tag by stackoverflow.

Comment: @RavishaHesh It is already having read permission for user,owner, group(rw-r--r--). Do i need to provide other permission using chmod ??. i can access chmod through SSH

Comment: Try with 755 permissions

Comment: Problem Solved : Best answer .Your Solution works. @lciamp Post your answer. i will make it the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Since you have SSH access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944532/how-to-install-laravel-5?noredirect=1#comment63347823_37944532) do this:

#### Filesystem

1. SSH into the server
2. Change directory to the project root

   - `cd /home/< username >`
3. delete the `public_html` folder

   - `rm -rf public_html`
4. create a symbolic link from `public` to `public_html`

   - `ln -s /home/< username >/public /home/< username >/public_html`
5. Install Laravel dependencies

   - `composer install`
6. Change permissions

   - `chmod -R 755 *`
   - `chmod -R 777 storage/ bootstrap/cache/`

#### Checklist

1. Make sure your environment file uploaded and is proper.
2. If the server is Apache, make sure you uploaded the `.htaccess` files.
3. You probably uploaded all the assets, if so you will not need to do bower or npm.
4. Restart the server.

#### **In Case of a Limited Shell Environment

1. Install Laravel dependencies locally and upload the `vendor` folder with everything else.
2. Instead of uploading the whole Laravel app to `/home/< username >/` upload it to `/home/< username >/public_html`.
3. Modify your `/home/< username >/public_html/.htaccess` to redirect all requests to the `public` subfolder.

   ```
   # /home/< username >/public_html/.htaccess

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
           Options -MultiViews
       </IfModule>

       RewriteEngine On

       # Redirect All Requests To The Subfolder
       RewriteRule ^ /public

   </IfModule>
   ```
4. Make sure you have the proper `/home/< username >/public_html/public/.htaccess` ([GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess)).

   ```
   # /home/< username >/public_html/public/.htaccess

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
           Options -MultiViews
       </IfModule>

       RewriteEngine On

       # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

       # Handle Front Controller...
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

       # Handle Authorization Header
       RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
       RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
   </IfModule>
   ```

Comment: You answer is correct but it wont work for my hosting provider they don't have all these function (rm,ln,composer) *FREE Suggest a hosting provider on which i can test and learn laravel on free real server is also an answer

Comment: clear,exit,arch,bzip2,cal,cksum,cmp,cp,crontab,basename,cd,chmod,ls,date,df,du,dos2unix,unix2dos,file,getfacl,gzip,head,hostid,tail,mkdir,mv,nslookup,sdiff,uptime,whois These are the commands they provide for SSH

Comment: To my knowledge there are not free server hosting options. The [Homestead vagrant box](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) is a real server that runs locally and there is no reason you cannot learn with that. I believe I have answered your question to the fullest. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

After you copy the code to your hosting server, you need to install the `composer` packages required to run Laravel. You can do this using `composer install` (providing that `composer` is installed). Otherwise, you need to install `composer` first.

Comment: He is trying it on shared or free hosting which has no shell access. So, how come he will run composer?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim He should run the composer installation on his local, and upload the vendor directory. Or, frankly, he should get off shared hosting entirely.

Comment: @ceejayoz as me mentioned "I had learned and done working codes in localhost." locally, he is ready. yes, agree! no shared hosting.