# How do you redirect all request to public/ folder in laravel 5

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I have a classic Larevel 5 project structure and I need to redirect all requests to `public/`.

I am on a classic hosting environment so `public/` is a subfolder of my document root.

I shall imagine it can be done via .htaccess but I still need to figure out how. Anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: Searching for [tag:.htaccess], [tag:laravel] and public: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.htaccess%5D+%5Blaravel%5D+public

Answer (score 82):

There are two solutions:

**1. Using .htaccess with mod_rewrite**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

**2. You can add a index.php file containing the following code and put it under your root Laravel folder (public_html folder).**

```
<?php
header('Location: public/');
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work 100% like it should, if I go to `localhost` it says _not found_ whilst when I go to `localhost/index.php` it gives the laravel homepage. It seems like you specifically have to type the full filename then. Any solutions for this behavior?

Comment: @JohannesB what's your development environment?

Comment: LAMP stack, `x86_64 Linux 4.15.12-1-ARCH`,   `Apache/2.4.29`,   `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.31-MariaDB` ,  `PHP 7.2.3`

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/TtSbvtwx) is what I am using now, it redirects to the index.php page to solve this issue, but it still seems weird and not the correct way to go

Comment: Following my preferred solution (your option 1)@MuhammadSumonMollaSelim I find that if I point to paths on my destination server that end with a back slash I get /public/ in the url.  

ie a request to www.test.com/page/ becomes www.test.com/public/page

Answer (score 26):

You don't need to change anything in Laravel's default **public/.htaccess** file.

Just create a new **.htaccess** in the same level your **public** folder and add the following content to it:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

That simple!

Answer (score 11):

This is an extract from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37949871/5816643) which may also help you.

--

- Modify your `public_html/.htaccess` to redirect all requests to the `public` subfolder.

  ```
  # public_html/.htaccess

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
          Options -MultiViews
      </IfModule>

      RewriteEngine On

      # Redirect All Requests To The Subfolder
      RewriteRule ^ /public

  </IfModule>
  ```
- Make sure you have the proper `public_html/public/.htaccess` ([GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess)).

  ```
  # public_html/public/.htaccess

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
          Options -MultiViews
      </IfModule>

      RewriteEngine On

      # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

      # Handle Front Controller...
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

      # Handle Authorization Header
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization}
      RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
  </IfModule>
  ```

Comment: its also working with CodeIgniter 4. Thanks for help.

Comment: This laravel crap changes with every release. I had this in a Laravel 5 installation. Same thing doesn't work at all in Laravel 7 installation. And yeah, the XAMPP stuff is all defined exactly the same. But now, Yii and Slim, they will work right out of the box. Laravel always gives me problems.

Answer (score 4):

If you use cPanel, then:

1.Go to folder:
**/var/cpanel/userdata/my_domain**

2.Edit the both domains:
**my.domain and my.domain_SSL**

Add to the documentroot section **/public**:

documentroot: /home/*user*/public_html/public

3.Rebuild Apache config:
**/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf && service httpd restart**

Comment: Not what op asked for.

Answer (score 4):

if you using apache , add .htaccess file to your root directory with this lines :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

and make sure your apache redirect and rewrite modules is working fine .
you can use vhost to redirect the all request to your public directory with set public as root of your project .

Answer (score 0):

The ideal scenario is to have `/home/user/public` as a symlink from `/home/user/laravel/public`.