# Laravel open index.html instead of going to route and opening the home page

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I am new to laravel and with server side  . The project is in laravel 5.0 and  i have this problem :

My project is working fine on localhost .

[image: project directory strucuture]

and the "framework" folder has structure of

[image]

In localhost project open the view returned in route ('/') but in server its opening index.html which is in root directory .

I think its something to do with server since its working well with localhost.

Comment: Laravel needs the server document root to be pointing to `/public` folder. Check that.

Comment: I have other laravel project in that server and that are working fine , but problem is with this project .

Comment: Ok, but did you check your .htaccess or nginx .conf files? Do they point to the right document root?

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
         RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]  is in htaccess file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040502/how-do-you-redirect-all-request-to-public-folder-in-laravel-5

Comment: you have to set your apache or nginx to run index.php first

Comment: It works if i rename my index.html to other name it work . it is working for all other route except  route at (' / ') when there is index.html in root directory

Comment: as per your server configuration, .html files may have precedence than .php files. you can confirm this by :browsing yourdomain.com/index.php.

You can set the preference (apache config )like this : DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm