# Laravel project works fine on localhost, but showing "500 Internal Server Error" or misconfiguration error on live (to xyz.com/lara)

Tags: php, laravel

I have developed small application in laravel, just on localhost.

Working fine.

Instead of "localhost:8000" url, I want "localhost/folder_name"

So, for that I just moved index.php & .htaccess file of public folder to root folder

& then I just make two line change in index.php as follow..

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

my current .htacsess code:

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**After uploading to it live server (to slash folder), its causing error**

**Showing error as follow:**

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@xyz.in to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Don't move index.php file. You need add redirect path to public folder within .htaccess file

Comment: Also, you can take a look in the log file (in  storage/logs) to see what is causing error?

Comment: @TigerTiger said it. Look in your error logs for more information

Comment: @RohitIUC I again moved index.php & .htaccess to public folder.. but now its showing "403 Forbidden or You dont have permission to access folder".. is there need to create another htaccess file for root folder too.. if yes then plz suugest me its code

Comment: there is no error in log files

Comment: Hi Amita I mean only index.php file move in public folder your htaccess file place on root of project.

Comment: @RohitIUC yes i moved .htaccess to root folder.. but though its showing "403 Forbidden" error.. just saying you dont have permission to access this folder.. plz suggest me whats missing with my htaccess

Comment: Ok,  @Amita maybe it link help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/38040902/9422926

Comment: obviously it will work for root folder.. but @RohitIUC my project to sub-folder like "xyz.com/lara".. then how can set.. I am trying with path changes but not happening

Comment: its just redirecting to /public.. not getting done