# How to Install my php (mvc architecture) on a apache server. Best way?

Tags: php, apache

Situation:
I have a website that iam working on, in my local machine
Server apache, php language.
In local i can access to the page by typing
http://localhost/(mysite)/public/index.php

Problem: 
In the  Hosting webserver, i want to access by 
simply  typing http://www.(mysite).com/index.php

Note: My website is based on  mvc (Model view controller) architecture.

Question: 
What is the appropriate way to « root » my website on the
 « public » directory in my apache server.

Should i point the hosting web server document root to The « public/«  directory ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040502/how-do-you-redirect-all-request-to-public-folder-in-laravel-5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you redirect all request to public/ folder in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040502/how-do-you-redirect-all-request-to-public-folder-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 3):

On linux go edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` or `mysite.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And append `/public` to whatever path you have as `DocumentRoot`