# Vue+laravel+apache not redirecting properly

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

Iḿ trying to run vue+laravel project without `php artisan serve` but when I acces localhost/project/public I see a blank page with this content only:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
    family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"><link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
</head>
 <body></body>
```

Despite this, when I acces localhost/project/public/any I see my default not found vue page so when I click go home button I can access my entire project without problems. Anyone can help to redirect properly to / route when going to  localhost/project/public.

Note: It works fine with `php artisan serve` and I'm trying this because I want to run my project in a ec2 instance but facing same probleme even with a virtual host to redirect to /project/public from .htacces
It's not a .htacces problem I can do the redirections as I want but when redirected to /public my vue file it's not being loaded, this is my app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
import App from './App.vue';
import store from './store';
import router from './router';
Vue.use(Vuetify)

require('./bootstrap');
const opts = {}
import ApiService from './api/api.service';

ApiService.init();
window.Vue = require('vue');
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    vuetify: new Vuetify(opts),
    components: { App },
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

this is my welcom.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- CSRF Token -->
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
      <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Administrador') }}</title>
      <!-- Scripts -->
      <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
      <!-- Fonts -->
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <!-- Styles -->
      <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="app">
        <index></index>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you redirect all request to public/ folder in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040502/how-do-you-redirect-all-request-to-public-folder-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running `php artisan serve` what are you running? Laravel requires the server to be running PHP in order to serve the welcome.blade.php file.

Comment: apache. it's solved I just had a index.html and index.php in my public folder LOL, when I delete index.html all run like a charm. And yes, with the right configuration you can run without ```php artisan serve```