# My web site's links are not working (404 NOT FOUND) on my server

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, laravel-8

My web site's links are not working.

My site : https://overlap.ulb.be/public/

When I click on a link, I have a 404 NOT FOUND (on any link)

If I click on the link "à propos" (about), I have this link :

https://overlap.ulb.be/about

**We can  see that I don't have anymore the public name in the URL.**

This is a part of my code (routes)

```
Route::get('about', [PlanteController::class, 'about']);
```

and the controller code :

```
    public function about()
  {
    return view('phyto.about' );
  }
```

And the view's code :

```
  <x-phyto-layout>

    <style>
      .h4-about-first {
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
      }
      .h4-about-m20 {
        margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
      }
      .h4-about {
        font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
        /*font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;*/
        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 120%;
        padding: 0;
        /*padding-left: 0px;*/
        /*margin: 0 0 10px;*/
        /*color: #413d3d;*/
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }
      .h4-about {
        font-size: 22px;
      }
      .p-about {
        font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 24px;
        color: #413d3d;
        /*margin: 0 0 18px 0;*/
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0;
        /*padding-left: 0px;*/
      }
    </style>

    <!-- About page container -->
    <div class="page-container">
      <div class="bloc bloc-fill-screen l-bloc" id="bloc-7">
        <div class="container fill-bloc-top-edge">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="bloc l-bloc" id="bloc-13" style="">
              <div class="container bloc-lg">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                    {{--<h3 style="font-size: 24px !important" class="mg-md h3-style">À propos de nous</h3>--}}
                    <h4 class="h4-about h4-about-first">À propos de nous</h4>
                    <p class="p-about" {{--style="color:black !important"--}}>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium adipisci alias aliquid at aut ea
                      eligendi, enim esse ex excepturi in ipsam neque odio praesentium repellendus sed tenetur totam unde.
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium adipisci alias aliquid at aut ea
                      eligendi, enim esse ex excepturi in ipsam neque odio praesentium repellendus sed tenetur totam unde.
                    </p>
                    {{--<h3 style="padding-top: 24px;font-size: 24px !important" class="mg-md h3-style">Projet Phyto ?</h3>--}}
                    <h4 class="h4-about h4-about-m20">Projet Phyto ?</h4>
                    <p class="p-about" {{--style="color:black !important"--}}>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium adipisci alias aliquid at aut ea
                      eligendi, enim esse ex excepturi in ipsam neque odio praesentium repellendus sed tenetur totam unde.
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium adipisci alias aliquid at aut ea
                      eligendi, enim esse ex excepturi in ipsam neque odio praesentium repellendus sed tenetur totam unde.
                    </p>
                    {{--<h3 style="padding-top: 24px;font-size: 24px !important" style="padding-top: 30px" class="mg-md h3-style">Collaborateurs</h3>--}}
                    <h4 class="h4-about h4-about-m20">Collaborateurs</h4>
                    <p class="p-about" {{--style="color:black !important"--}}>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium adipisci alias aliquid at aut ea
                      eligendi, enim esse ex excepturi in ipsam neque odio praesentium repellendus sed tenetur totam unde.
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium adipisci alias aliquid at aut ea
                      eligendi, enim esse ex excepturi in ipsam neque odio praesentium repellendus sed tenetur totam unde.
                    </p>

                    <h4 class="h4-about h4-about-m20">Nom latin</h4>
                    <p class="p-about" {{--style="color:black !important"--}}>
                      Le nom latin fait référence à la dernière classification (lien : www.derniere-classification.org)
                    </p>

                    <a href="/gpd?p=search" class="btn btn-lg btn-more-link-style btn-sq btn-golden-green float-lg-none mt-5">
                      Recherche de plantes
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- bloc-7 END -->



Thank you














{{--<div class="bloc none l-bloc" id="home-about">
      <div class="container bloc-xl">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2 order-md-1">
            <img src="/images/valeriane_rouge.jpg" data-src="/images/valeriane_rouge.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block lazyloaded">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2  align-self-center">
            <h2 class="mg-md titulo01 h2-margin-bottom">Qu'est ce que ULB-PHYTO?</h2>
            <p class="parrafo01">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus dicta error explicabo,
              harum hic ipsam laboriosam molestiae nihil odit optio porro provident repellendus
              saepe sed sequi similique velit vitae, voluptatem?
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A accusantium amet delectus,
              dicta dolor ea eligendi ex, excepturi facere
              incidunt iste maiores porro possimus, qui rerum velit vitae voluptatem! Repudiandae.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>--}}


I also have a .htaccess :

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: add public to your document root in your vhost httpd.conf

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I don't have access to apache server, can I use a .htaccess ? Thank you again Martin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040502/how-do-you-redirect-all-request-to-public-folder-in-laravel-5

Comment: Thank you Martin, I tried everything, but unfortunately, nothing is working.  My links still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue was not loading your asset correctly. you can put the full URL of styles and javascript in your app layout including the public or you can use the asset function to generate a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
```

if you are using the asset method you should put the ASSET_URL variable in your .env file

```
ASSET_URL=https://overlap.ulb.be/public
```

UPDATED
if you mean images in your style you have two solutions, you can write inline style in your blade in this case you can use the asset method like the above example OR change all background URLs in the external style CSS file with

```css
background-image: url("/public/images/...");
```

Comment: Thank you Esmail, my site works at 95% now.  I still have a problem with the main photo (flower) of my site.  It does not appear.  Thank you again.