# How to make my route accessible without using public in shared hosting using laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

How to make my route accessible without using public in shared hosting using laravel, I tried to use this .htaccess but it is not working

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

Im currently using hostinger and my folder structure is

->public_html
->laravel files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L0N2.png)

My index is inside public folder

I tried this .htaccess code but not working

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

My index is inside public folder

Answer (score 2):

Move your `index.php` and `.htaccess` files under the public folder to parent folder.
Don't forget to fix the paths in your `index.php` file. Like this:

```
// require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'; to...
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Your project will be triggered in **public_html**.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for this case is by creating htaccess like this : [How do you redirect all request to public/ folder in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040502/how-do-you-redirect-all-request-to-public-folder-in-laravel-5)

But we still have a "not too recommended" trick to handle limited functionality of hosting provider :

1. Move all files in your project file (except "public" directory), and create new "private" folder. In this step, the "private" and "public" folder are in same level like this :

```
- private
   - app
   - bootstrap 
   - config
   - database
   - ...
- public
   - index.php
   - your_assets_or_anything
   - ...
```

2. Move all "public" directory content to root project. In this step, the directory structure will be like this :

```
- private
   - app
   - bootstrap 
   - config
   - database
   - ...
- index.php
- your_assets_or_anything
- ...
```

3. Last open the "index.php" file that currently in root directory, replace all `/../` with `/private/` . Example :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
// ...
if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/private/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}
// ...
require __DIR__.'/private/vendor/autoload.php';
// ...
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/private/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Keep in mind that this trick have a security issue. You need to protect all private files from public access.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in **.htaccess** in **public_html**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Insert below code in **.htaccess** placed under **public** folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the easiest way to redirect your requests to make your site live.