# How to deploy Laravel (with Filament) to a cPanel shared hosting in separate folders?

Tags: laravel, shared

I have a Laravel + Filament environment running locally and I had setup some Github actions to deploy on a shared hosting, depending on the pushed branch (branch develop -> develop public_html/develop directory and branch staging -> public_html/staging directory).

I setup the database and .env file.

When I push to develop, the Action clones the repo at develop branch and runs composer install and the migrations, but it is not working:

- If I go to /develop it raises 403
- If I go to /develop/public it shows the default laravel page
- If I go to /develop/public/admin it shows the default Filament login form (and it is correct!), but when I enter the user and password the page does not change (only refreshes)

I do not know how to setup the htaccess files neither where to put the files properly.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just try following answer.

[How do you redirect all request to public/ folder in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040502/how-do-you-redirect-all-request-to-public-folder-in-laravel-5)

This is what I did:

COPY htaccess file from the public folder to the root folder (keep the original file in public only) and add two extra lines to the htaccess file in the root folder.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Root folder htaccess file looks like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Remove public URL from the path
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this answer will help!

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in you user model

```html
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Filament\Models\Contracts\FilamentUser;
use Filament\Panel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
 
class User extends Authenticatable implements FilamentUser
{
    // ...
 
    public function canAccessPanel(Panel $panel): bool
    {
        return str_ends_with($this->email, '@yourdomain.com') && $this->hasVerifiedEmail();
    }
}
```

If you don't complete these steps, a 403 Forbidden error will be returned when accessing the app in production.

Find more info here https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/installation#deploying-to-production

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).